# MySql Query to Postgres Query. Postges Not supporting IF Condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, laravel

I gonging to change my laravel application database mysql to postgres. I am using raw query
Here is my query:

```
select IF (modelno="" OR modelno IS NULL,name,concat(name, " / ",modelno)) as name, id from `models` where `deleted_at` is null order by `name` asc
```

when i use this query for postgres the following exception raised.

> zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" LINE 1: select IF
>   (modelno="" OR modelno IS NULL,name,concat(name, '...

And my larvel controler code is following and works fine with MySql:

```
DB::table('models')
    ->select(DB::raw('IF (modelno="" OR modelno IS NULL,name,concat(name, " / ",modelno)) as name, id'))
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->lists('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think postgres supports IF, so try CASE :

```
DB::table('models')
    ->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN modelno="" OR modelno IS NULL then name else concat(name, " / ",modelno) as name, id'))
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->lists('name', 'id');
```

Comment: Thanks. but case statement does not work for me. my problem is solved with where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres do not support `IF` statement in Query.
But the solution for this issue could be handled with `where` class.

#### Here is Example:

```
DB::table('models')
    ->select(DB::raw("concat(name, modelno) as name, id"))
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->where('modelno','=','')
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->orWhereNull('modelno')
    ->lists('name', 'id');
```